# How to avoid typing passphrase for public key when using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, sshpass

If I want to use password, I can do it by:

```
`sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' your_password) ssh user@hostname`
```

But sshpass seems not working for public key. I tried the following command and it failed:

```
`sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' your_passphrase) ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user@hostname`
```

Is there any good way to do so?

Comment: you can try [passh](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `sshpass` option `-P` to detect the passphrase prompt:

```
sshpass -Ppassphrase -f <(printf '%s\n' your_passphrase) ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user@hostname
```

Comment: there's a missing space in `-Ppassphrase` (should be `-P passphrase`), moreover there's no need to use `printf` and especially `sshpass`'s option `-f` (which is used to pass a file containing a password), but use `-p` instead (with which you can insert the password diretly). Of course this method is unsecure if you're inserting in your command line directly, in which case I would suggest to save the password to a file and provide the filename with `-f`.

So a simplier command could be
`sshpass -P passphrase -p your_passphrase ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user@hostname`

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you want to use `sshpass` in order to put in the public key?

If you want to use your public key with no password prompt from an interactive situation, just use an [ssh agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent). At least on Ubuntu, it runs by default. All you have to do is add the keys you want to it and enter the password once.

If you want to do so from a script, just create an unencrypted version of the key. It is as secure (if not more secure) than using `sshpass`, and saves the hassle of using another program.

On a personal note, I wrote, from scratch, several open source projects. Of the four or so that gained some popularity, none surprised me more than `sshpass`. It was a single day of work meant to solve a specific corner case.
I get it that it turned out to be much more useful than I originally anticipated, but I really don't see any case where it makes sense to use it if public key authentication is an option.

Comment: the problem with the ssh agent is that when executing `ssh-add`, passphrase is required, but I need the whole procedure to be non-interactive. the reason is that I am developing a project in which it is required to execute command as other users, whose usernames and public keys are given.

Comment: @yurenzhong Then use `ssh-keygen` to remove the password from the private key. This solution is still more secure than storing the password in the script file.

Comment: @Harvett: you might want to use [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/)